# How to get HTML/SVG object to intercept touch events but be transparent for mouse events?

Tags: css, html, svg, d3.js

In my web UI, i would like to have totally different response to mouse and touch events in the same screen area. I see the solution to position a blank container (either `div` or `SVG rect`) over the area in order to capture only the touch events for the entire space, while mouse events would reach out to the specific objects underneath.

The question is: how do i make this container sensitive to touch events (as if it had `CSS` property `pointer-events: visible;`) but transparent for mouse event (as if it had `CSS` property `pointer-events: none;`)?

Unfortunately, the mentioned CSS property modifies the behavior together for mouse and touch.
Thanks!

Comment: You could check in your event handler what type of event it is and either pass it on to the next handler if it's a mouse event.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought. But i can't find the method to pass the event to the next handler (provided that i don't know in advance which element would happen to be the next). Would you mind to give a code example?

Comment: Events are actually bubbled up automatically (see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)), so you would need to stop those that you're handling with [`.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation).